# error: Undefined name 'widget' in Dart when trying to build navigation

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Can someone help me? Newbie with Flutter here.

I have this:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final Place? place;
  const SecondRoute({Key? key, this.place}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text(widget.place!.text!),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And:

```
class PlaceDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final Place? place;

  PlaceDetail({Key? key, this.place}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlaceDetailState createState() {
    return _PlaceDetailState();
  }
}
```

I successfully can navigate to the next page, but the problem is with this part:

```
child: Text(widget.place!.text!)
```

**I am trying to show some content that I fetch with JSON. In a different widget, that specific widget.place!.text! works like a charm, but in this class and widget, I can't get it to work and t thus I get the error:**

```
error: Undefined name 'widget'
```

If I extend it to State , I get the error:

```
error: The return type 'SecondRoute' isn't a 'Widget'
```

I tried to follow the documentation here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

As I mentioned, the navigation itself works, but trying to fetch data from JSON that I had in a widget gives me the error.

**Edit:**

```
Text(${place?.text!}")
```

The above gives me NULL. Any chance I can get this variable sent to the new page/screen without giving me NULL value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
child: Text(widget.place!.text!)
```

should be

```
child: Text(this.place!.text!)
```

or simply

```
child: Text(place!.text!)
```

Although you should think about your usage of `!`. It *should* not be neccessary here.

Comment: If I do that, I get: error: The getter 'text' isn't defined for the type 'Place'

Comment: I guess your "Place" class doesn't have a text property?

Comment: You mean Place.dart? It has lists, strings, ints... and as I mentioned, it works in other widgets in the same file. What and where should I check?

Comment: uh... you should check whether your `Place` class has a property or field called `text`. Your compiler says it doesn't, I'm inclined to believe it.

Comment: Sorry, got you! It says, after I click to the new page and try to see the new text: Null check operator used on a null value. How can I solve that?

Comment: Okay, interestingly enough this works: place?.text!, but now the text is fully empty.. it's not outputting anything ---__---

Comment: What do you think those `?` and `!` do? If you are sure it must be filled, why is it a nullable property?

Comment: The idea here is to show the field if they exist. I do that in my other widget as well and that works. The problem I have is that the text is not being shown: it seems to be empty (like it's not taken to the next screen?). Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: If I do this: Text(${place?.text!}") it says NULL. Is there a different way I can set or fetch the variable? I mean, they are on the same page and it works on other widgets. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the point of "nullable". Maybe you should take a step backand read a tutorial. If you are sure that "place" and "text" *cannot* be null, then just make the variable not null (remove the ? after the type) and your compiler will tell you exactly where you forgot to assign it.

Comment: That's the thing, when I remove that, I get the error "Null check operator used on a null value" and my console says error: The property 'text' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null', which is the same line as I am trying to remove the ? after the type.

Comment: Text("${place?.text ??""}") solves the NULL issue, but again: there is nothing spit out. It's just empty...

Comment: Ah, yes, because it *is* null. Show me the line where you assign something. Show me why it *should not* be null.

Comment: Container(
 child: widget.place!.text!.isNotEmpty
                                  ? Text(widget.place!.text ?? "" ,
) This spits out the text perfectly (so, it's not NULL) in a different widget in the same file. I am fetching this from the JSON file, so I know it can't be empty. What I struggle with, probably, is the fact that variable is not being pushed to the next screen / page.

Comment: Perhaps because I am not passing it here?                                   Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),

Comment: Yes, indeed. Please note that if you had not made the `place` field nullable, but instead had `required` it, *your compiler* would already have told you that, because not filling it there would have been a compiler error instead of an hour long debugging journey. Null-Safety is good and useful, learn what it does and use it to your advantage.